# Marshalling c# unsigned char* insiede a struct

Tags: c#, marshalling

I've a problem using P\Invoke in C#. I've to Marshal a struct like the following on

```
typedef struct MyStruct
{
    enum1 TagType;
    unsigned char *Id;
    int Length;
    enum2 Antenna;
    enum3 Input
}
```

I've problems Marshalling the ID field. I've tried the following code but Marshal.PrtToStructure throws an error about structur not matching to metadata...

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct MyStruct
{
     enum1 TagType;
     byte[] ID;
     int Length;
     enum2 Antenna;
     enum3 Input;
}
```

How can i solve ?

Comment: It is not a byte[] because the bytes would be continuous.  You have a pointer to a char array so use IntPtr idPtr.  You will need later in code to get the characters from the pointer.

Comment: A byte[] requires too much secret knowledge that the pinvoke marshaller cannot know.  How many elements in the array?  Well, maybe Length, but the marshaller does not know that.  How is the storage for the native array supposed to be released?  Well, nobody knows.  You'll have to use `IntPtr` and marshal yourself with Marshal.Copy().  And you can't release memory so you'd better call this function a hundred million times in a test program to verify that you don't have a memory leak.